# Missing create2 opcode in ethereum yellow paper

Tags: opcode, yellow-paper

In [eip 1014](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1014.md) Vitalik added Create2 at opcode 0xf5

> Adds a new opcode at 0xf5

But in [ethereum yellow paper opcode](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf#subsection.H.2) i don't see opcode 0xf5 or any create2 opcode, it doesn't appear in https://www.ethervm.io/ either. But in https://github.com/crytic/evm-opcodes opcode 0xf5 create2 appears in it.

My question: why does ethereum yellow paper doesn't have anything about it, even they have add new opcode in 0xf5? Is it because they forget to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yellow paper isn't maintained much anymore due to the high-level of academic experience needed to update it, as well as the moderate technical experience needed to interpret it. The [Jellopaper](https://jellopaper.org/evm/?highlight=create2) is a much more up to date and readable resource, and includes the `create2` opcode you reference.